# Read textbox from ASP.net page that repeated n times

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net web page that's has a number of controls that are repeated according to number of records retrieved from the database, and I wanna read the values of those text boxes after users enter values in them, so please if anyone can help me on this issue.

I have an example of my work

```
    <% System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader myDReader = myDatabaseConnector.getDataFromDBAsSQLDataReader("SELECT * from students);
       while(myDReader.Read())
       { %>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtCourseInfo" Test="" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="dataEntrySearchDataText" ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <% } %>
```

This a sample of what I have mean from my question in which I want to retrieve the value of txtCourseInfo in my C# code behind

Comment: Is this displaying the list of students when run??

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Repeater to do this:

```
<asp:repeater id="rptCourses" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsCourseInfo" 
   <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCourseInfo" Text='<%#Eval("StudentName")#%>' EnableViewState="false" CssClass="dataEntrySearchDataText" ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:sqldatasource id="dsCourseInfo"  
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:YourConnectionString %>" 
Select Command="Select * from Students">
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

That's all you need. from code behind you can iterate through the controls on the repeater and grab the information.

Notice the `Eval` expression on the text field. I used "StudentName" as an example, but you should use one of the column names returned by the `select statement`

**Additional comments:**

1. Don't do `select * from ...`  It's a bad practice in many respects. Always specify the columns you need, even if you need all.
2. I realize that you disable viewstate on the textbox. I don't know the reason for doing this but be aware that the info won't be persisted on subsequent postbacks unless you enable it on the control.

**UPDATE**

Yes, you can have tables inside repeaters. Look at the example below:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
            <table runat="server" style="color: White; background-color: #3A4F63;" visible="false"
                id="headerTable">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="headerTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 200px; background-color: #3A4F63; color: White;">
                        Image 
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 200px;">
                        Studen Name
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 200px;">
                        Birth Date
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
             <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 200px;">
                        <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>'></asp:Image>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 200px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 200px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblBirthDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BirthDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I know there is a repeater control, but is it possible to use the repeater to repeat a HTML tags such as HTML Table <table> ... etc? and BTW inside my loop there is a nested loop retrieve another data from database according to a value retrieved from main loop value.

Comment: @MohammedAl-Farhan: I posted an update. Regarding your inner loop to retrieve extra information, you can handle OnRowDataBound, read the particular row's value, gather the extra info you need and bind it to some other control inside your ItemTemplate.

Comment: Thank you very much I am gonna user the above code and I'll see what happen